# SQL Server: Recursive dynamic SQL puzzle

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I was looking at [this post of trim all columns of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552154/sql-server-how-to-perform-rtrim-on-all-varchar-columns-of-a-table). In the answer query script the column names gets concatenated without any looping operation. I simplified it to check its work flow as explained below.

- Create a new database
- Create a new table with three columns as in below script.(insert
  values not required)

  ```
  Create table table1(id int, name varchar(20), city varchar(20))
  ```

  Execute below T-SQL Script, which results `xxx [id] [name] [city]`  in single row.

  ```
  Declare @a as varchar(4000)
  SET @a = 'xxx '
  SELECT @a = @a + '['+COLUMN_NAME+'] ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  SELECT @a
  ```

Where as below script results in 3 rows

```
Declare @a as varchar(4000)
SET @a = 'xxx '
SELECT 'b' = @a + '['+COLUMN_NAME+'] ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

To understand more better I executed the below query using `Top 1`. This results `xxx [id]`

```
Declare @a as varchar(4000)
SET @a = 'xxx '
SELECT Top 1 @a = @a + '['+COLUMN_NAME+'] ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
SELECT @a
```

I got puzzled With Top 2 query. This resulted `xxx [id] [name]`.

Where as I was expecting `xxx [id] xxx [id] [name]` i.e. First value + second value. Where am I going wrong.

I am curious to know how the column names getting concatenated. Sorry I could not frame better title for this puzzle.

Comment: First of all, please stop using single quotes around column aliases (as in `'b' = ...`) – that is just [**bad**](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases). Secondly, what does the `'b' = ...` example have to do with your question anyway? Or are you also confusing cases like `SELECT columnalias = ...` and `SELECT @variablename = ...`? You should probably ask about those separately.

Comment: What is the expected results for TOP(3)?

Comment: @AndriyM - Aaron Bertrand 's article was informative. My clear question is without looping how values are getting concatenated. You can ignore `'b'=...` query part. I just put that code for comparison or some reference.

Answer (score 7):

> I am curious to know how the column names getting concatenated.

Can't really answer that. Some internal workings of SQL Server creates a result like that, sometimes.

The technique has been around for a considerable amount of time. Microsoft does not support the functionality and advises not to use it.

From [SET @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx)

> Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values
>   (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may
>   occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including
>   assignments) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each
>   output row.

Instead you can use a cursor or the `for xml` trick to do the same.

```
declare @a as varchar(4000);
set @a = 'xxx ';

set @a = @a + (
              select quotename(COLUMN_NAME) as '*'
              from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              for xml path(''), type
              ).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(4000)');
```

Result: `xxx [city][id][name]`

Comment: Though, if we follow to the [KB artible](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us), it states `You may encounter unexpected results when you apply any operators or expressions to the ORDER BY clause of aggregate concatenation queries`, which is not the case. This is just a simple concatenation which works as expected

Comment: @user16484 I can think of at least three other "expected" results with a syntax like that and the text in the documentation does not say that it works nor how it works when you omit the order by clause.

Comment: You're right as to the order of the results as we are not forcing them;) still, in a concatenation without any further expressions/operations, I can't see how the result could be different in the sense of `'xxx '` appearing more than once; they do state that the unexpected results is an issue `when you apply any operators or expressions to the ORDER BY clause`

Comment: @user16484 the KB article only mentions `order by` but the responses on the connect site indicate this is not supported or guaranteed ever. Some example quotes here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15163136/73226 especially `Even without ORDER BY, we do not guarantee that @var = @var + will produce the concatenated value for any statement that affects multiple rows. The right-hand side of the expression can be evaluated either once or multiple times during query execution and the behavior as I said is plan dependent.`

Answer (score 0):

After several experiments I am here [answering my same question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). This works as our traditional `a = a + 1` method.

Run queries one by one as below to understand the flow of task.

**Example1:**

**Query 1:** Below query returns `1@[id]`. Meaning @a = ***`1@[id]`***

```
Declare @a as varchar(4000)
SET @a = 1
SELECT Top 1 @a = @a + '@' + '['+COLUMN_NAME+']'  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
SELECT @a
```

**Query 2:** Below query returns `1@[id]@[name]`. Meaning @a = ***`1@[id]`*** + `@ + [name]`

```
Declare @a as varchar(4000)
SET @a = 1
SELECT Top 2 @a = @a + '@' + '['+COLUMN_NAME+']' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
SELECT @a
```

**Query 3:** Below query returns `1@[id]@[name]@[city]`. Meaning @a = ***`1@[id]@[name]`*** + `@ + [City]`

```
Declare @a as varchar(4000)
SET @a = 1
SELECT Top 3 @a = @a + '@' + '['+COLUMN_NAME+']'  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
SELECT @a
```

**Example 2:**

You can run top 1, top 2, top 3 queries for the below and know the flow. This is going to return `'# '` 8 times. This query illustration is without column names.

```
Declare @a as varchar(4000)
SET @a = '# '
SELECT Top 3 @a = @a + @a  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
SELECT @a
```

**OUTPUT :**  `# # # # # # # #`